# How to do pgr_analyzeoneway pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, network-analyst, road, pgadmin-3, pgr-dijkstra

I try to do pgr_analyzeoneway to my network road data from OSM.
But there's some parameter that I don't know what I should input event though already read the example:

```
s_in_rules: text[] source node in rules
s_out_rules:    text[] source node out rules 
t_in_rules: text[] target node in rules 
t_out_rules:    text[] target node out rules
```

for 4 parameters above, should I put the default one from the example?

```
oneway: text oneway column name name of the network table. Default value is oneway
```

and this one, what should I put the attribute?

Yes&No? Oneway&Null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneway is the column name in your table which you are using to keep information about direction of line segment. In the documentation they have B= Both direction, TF = To to From(going in reverse direction is only allowed), FT = From to To (going in forward direction is only allowed) stored in 'oneway' column. If u have the same data they have, u can use the same rules in example. Those are basically rules telling what type of connected line segements are not allowed. For example I have a straight path starting from point A to point B formed of 5 line segments and there 'oneway' column has values 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'. Here all the 5 line segements have value 'B' = Both direction. So this is valid topology and user can get direction from point A to B or from B to A. But if had values 'B', 'B', 'TF', 'FT', 'B', here the topology fails as one line TF is connected to line segment having value FT. [image: Flow of direction] So neither we get route from point A to B nor from point B to A if we follow oneway rule. So pgr_analyzeoneway help us find such error in our data

Comment: thanks sir, i got it. the answer also explained in [pgrouting's sample data](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html#sampledata), but since i use osm data, i have to syncronise with the attribute and the documentation